# Showing type of newline character in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I have Emacs display the type of new character?

I am looking for something similar to what Notepadd does (see below). I read that Emacs comes with `M-x whitespace-mode` but this doesn't seem to show the type of ASCII control character the file uses to represent linebreaks. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82536/showing-type-of-newline-character-in-emacs

Comment: @DerHochstapler, in fact the question was done first here and then in unix SE.

Comment: @DerHochstapler This is a legiti question about how to use a Computer Software named Emacs. Should you reconsider to open it again? I have the same exact question and don't want to open a new one, just upvoted for it and wold like to star a bounty.

Comment: @amelio-vazquez-reina I'm looking for a solution to this answer, and I think whitespace mode could be it... or at least it's mechanism to rewrite a character via a display_mapping.

Comment: @jgomo3 Feel free to contribute to the question on unix.se. No idea what the misunderstanding here is.

Comment: @DerHochstapler I'm reading a note that says: "closed as off-topic by Der Hochstapler". And I think is not off-topic for the reasons I already mentioned. And Emacs is not exclusive to Unix, so I think This Stack is the best place for the question.

Comment: @jgomo3 If you think it's worth to debate with me if a 5 year old question should be on site A or site B, then you need to find a better way to spend your time. Content shouldn't be cross-posted on multiple sites. End of story

Comment: @DerHochstapler is not personal, and I'm not trying to debate. I was asking you to do something as I identified you as the "Authority" to address such request, and exposing to you support to my petition.

I see I wrote "Should you reconsider to open it again?", but I meant "Could you reconsider to open it again, Please?".
Why to invest "extra" effort in this old content? Because the point of StackOverflow is to keep the best quality of content for posterity: Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it might be good enough.

If you know the native line ending convention for the platform you're on, you can look on the left side of the Emacs mode line. If the file uses a non-native convention, you should see a notation like `(DOS)` or `(Unix)`. If there's no notation, then that implies the native convention. From that, you can figure out what each line ends in.

So, for example, if you're running Emacs on a Unix system, and you open a file with DOS line endings, you should see `(DOS)` in the lower left of the screen.

If the line ending convention in the file is inconsistently applied, then you'll see stray `^M` or `^J` characters.